# Hot Reload and Runtime Compilation Blazor Webassembly hosted

Tags: visual-studio, razor, blazor

I am developing a Blazor Webassembly hosted project with VS2019. Each time I change something in the razor pages, I have to recompile it. Which options are there to see changes in a preview or hot reload or what so ever?

I tried some Google solutions but they are not working. Adding the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation Nuget to my Server solution and add it in Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

has no effect and to the client solution it raised a error. Are there any problems in Blazor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5 you can use the `dotnet watch run` command from a cmd line prompt on the folder with your CSPROJ file.

Comment: Plz tell me why this is not the default debugging mode???